# MMDrawerController Pre Built Animations with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, mmdrawercontroller

I'm using `MMDrawerController`, and I'm trying to change the way the drawer slides out.

In objective C, I would do

```
[drawerController setDrawerVisualStateBlock:[MMDrawerVisualState slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock]]
```

to change how the drawer slides out to the `Slide and Scale` animation.

In Swift however, I can't seem to be able to do this. This is where I'm at with swift:

```
drawerController.setDrawerVisualStateBlock { (MMDrawerController!, MMDrawerSide, CGFloat) -> Void in

}
```

I'm unable to call something like this `MMRawerVisualState.slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock()` inside the block. Is this feature not supported with Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-c you were passing a class method witch returns a block for the animation(typelias of `MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock`). But you're not passing the same method in the swift version of the code(You're implementing it).

```
drawerController.setDrawerVisualStateBlock(MMDrawerVisualState.slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock)
```

Comment: this is actually the code I had to use: `drawerController.setDrawerVisualStateBlock(MMDrawerVisualState.slideAndScaleVisualStateBlock()!)` Cheers!

Comment: Both of you, Your answer is awesome. Thanks.